# how to use where condion on selected result in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
I want all country name in result along with those whose sel_id is  1
```

I have 2 tables country table and price_plan_detail

```
country table
    Id name
    1 India
    2 china
    3 bangladesh
    4 china

price_plan_detail
id country_id_fk  name     sel_id
1    1           india 1   1
2    1           india 2   1 
3    1           india 3   2
4    1           china 1   2
5    2           china 1   1
6    2           china 2   2
```

I want all the country from country table and all the matching record from price_plan_detail table which having sel id as 1.

```
india   India 1     1
india   India 2     1
china   china 1     1
india   null        NULL
india   Null        Null
china   null        null
bangladesh  NULL    NULL
shrilanka   NULL    NULL
```

I want this result.

This is my query

```
 SELECT * from  (select c.name,p.name as p,p.sel_id as sel_id from country as c LEFT join price_plan_detail as p ON p.`country`=c.id) as t WHERE t.sel_id=1
```

with this query i got wrong result

```
name    p   sel_id  
india   India 1     1
india   India 2     1
china   china 1     1
```

This is my result which is wrong here I want all the countries with sel_id 1
    I want all country name in result along with those whose sel_id is  1

Comment: Can you quickly provide the DML and DDL or make an SQLFiddle.com? It's easy I believe. I can solve it.

Comment: What's the 4th column you have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: sel_id is my fouth column from price_plan_detail table

Comment: Now I understand. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `sel_id=1` filter criterion from the `where` clause to the join condition because the `where` clause is applied after the tables were joined.

```
select c.name,p.name as pname,p.sel_id as sel_id
from country as c
LEFT join price_plan_detail as p
    ON p.`country`=c.id and p.sel_id=1
```